# Ember load template on the fly with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

I would like to load html from another html file as needed with the following code:

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
  template:function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'views/main.html',
       dataType: 'text',
       async: false,
       success: function (res) {
         returnnow(res);
       }
    });
    function returnnow(res){
      return Ember.Handlebars.compile(res);
    }
  }
});
```

But it returns nothing.. Probably issued to the asynchronous character of ajax.

I can't just wrap the View with an Ajax because I first want to load it when I call the view.

Any Ideas how to perform this ?

Comment: instead of url: 'views/main.html' try url: 'views/main.php'. Also there is some issue with Ember.Handlebars.compile. Even though you get a compiled return. You wont be able to render it. There is some error called "not able to push or something". However i am pretty sure u cant use html for ajax response

Comment: The Ajax load itself works quite fine I double checked on this. The Problem is that return is function scoped.. but I don't have a better Idea right now. Maybe `Ember.RSVP.Promise`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting nothing because your `template` function doesn't return anything. You need to change your code like this:

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: function(){
       var result;
       $.ajax({
            url: 'views/main.html',
            success: function(data) {
                result = Ember.Handlebars.compile(data);
            }
       });
       return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Because Ajax works async your code produce nothing and if I set async: false I got this : `function (c, f) {f=f||{};var g,h,i=f.partial?f:b;f.partial||(g=f.helpers,h=f.partials);var j=a.call(e,i,c,g,h,f.data);return f.partial||d(e.compilerInfo),j;}`